Missing Implicit Definition Constraints in Mathematical Equations
let's look at the example
sqrt(y)+x=c

from the root I understand that there is an "immediate" definition constraint: y>=0
thus c-x>=0
thus c>=x and let's call it an "implicit definition constraint"

This "new definition  constraint" affects my final drawing of the graph
because if I want to rewrite the sqrt(y)+x=c as a function of y, I will use the power of 2 for     both sides I will finally get a parabola  and it would be a mistake to draw it in exam:

Scenario
Let's suppose I missed this "implicit definition constraint", did the work, and got the parabola. I can still be "saved" because I know that squaring (or any even power) can be problematic. I can try substituting some X values greater than C into the parabola equation, and I will discover that the original equation does not hold in such cases. Thus, I was "saved" because of the "red alarm" from squaring, even though I missed the "implicit definition constraint" issue.
Question:
Are there cases, particularly where squaring is not needed, where if I forgot to calculate the "implicit definition constraint", I will get wrong answers (ones that do not meet the "implicit definition constraint" which I forgot to calculate), but this time, unlike in the parabola case, those answers will still hold the original equation? If yes, could you please provide a couple of examples?
Thank you very much for reading and trying to understand my question

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Answer to your question: There are no such examples. If something satisfies the given equation, it cannot be called wrong, because well, there is nothing wrong with it.

Now, let me present some logic that describes, where does errors in our solutions can come from.
Let's consider sitution, where we work with some equality involving two real variables $x$ and $y$, in particular:
$$F(x,y) = G(x,y)$$
where $F$ and $G$ describes some expressions that involve $x$ and $y$ as unknown and both have some domains, on which they are defined.
For example in your question you have:
$$F(x,y) = \sqrt{y} + x \qquad G(x,y) = c \quad \text{(Here G is a constant expression)}$$
where of $F$ consists of all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $y \geqslant 0$
and domain of G is set of all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.
In general the equation $F(x,y) = G(x, y)$ makes sense only for those $x,y$ that belong to both domains of $F$ and $G$.

Let's now invesitage what actually happens, when we manipulate that kind of equation. In fact we generate the sequence of equations:
$$F_1(x,y) = G_1(x,y)$$
$$F_2(x,y) = G_2(x,y)$$
$$\vdots$$
$$F_n(x,y) = G_n(x,y)$$
where the last is most likely the simplest form that wecan achieve. Now, when we do this those equations are related to each other by either $\boxed{\implies}$ or $\boxed{\iff}$.
For example:
$$x + 2 = y \quad \boxed{\iff} \quad x = y - 2$$
but:
$$x = -2 \quad \boxed{\implies} \quad x^2 = 4$$
and it is not true, that $\color{red}{x^2 = 4 \iff x = -2}$ because $-2$ is not the only solution to $x^2 = 4$.
Moreover one should keep in mind, that transitions $\implies$ can become $\iff$ in some domains. For example:
$$x = 5 \implies x^2 = 25 \quad \text{for } x\in \mathbb{R}$$
but:
$$x = 5 \iff x^2 = 25 \quad \text{for } x \geqslant 0$$

If all transitions are of the form $\iff$, then all solutions to final equality also satisfy the starting equality (because those are like "bidirectional" transitions - pair $(x,y)$ satisfy either both or none of the equations).
The problem appears if there is at least one transition of the form $\implies$. This transition does not allow us to conclude, that every solution to the final equation will satisfy the first one.
However, all solutions to the first equation are also solutions to the last equation. This is beacuse $p \implies q$ means "if $p$ then $q$", so if some pair $(x,y)$ satisfies first eqaution, then it must also satisfy all consequtive equations. So set of all solutions to first equation is a subset of set of solutions to last equation. Now we try use the last derived equation to check, which of its solutions satisfy the first equation (because from what was said previously we know, that there can't be other solutions satisfying the first equation apart from those that satisfy the last equation).
In your problem:
$$\sqrt{y} + x = c \iff \sqrt{y} = c - x \implies y = (c-x)^2$$
Now if we plug the last equation to first one we will get:
$$\sqrt{(c-x)^2} + x = c$$
$$|c-x| + x = c$$
And this equation holds only for $x \leqslant c$. Thus the set of solutions can be described as:
$$y = (c-x)^2 \quad \text{where } x \leqslant c$$

Here is another problem that can appear. Anytime we manipulate the given equation, we must make sure that we we not change unintentionally the domain that we work with.
For example:
$$x = y \implies \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{y}$$
but $\sqrt{x}$ is defined only on $\mathbb{R}_+$, so if original domain was $\mathbb{R}$, then we won't find all solutions.
In fact we sometimes want to change the domain, but then we split problem into cases and solve them separately.

Thank you for a very detailed answer!
If I solve the original equation by squaring both sides I will finally get y=x^2cx+c^2
Solving it leads to only one answer X=c which holds the original equation.
But can this information be helpful in understanding that I have to avoid drawing the full parabola?
The goal of the exercise was to draw a function, while discussed scenario is accidentally missing a step of checking the so called "implicit definition constraint" c>=x.
Guess that skipping led to inevitable mistake, in the sense that there will be no more red flags in the pipeline. Right?

When you square both sides your transition is $\implies$. If you add a constraint that both sides must have the same sign (non-negative or non-positive) then transition becomes $\iff$ so it is fine. Moreover this constraint does not ommit any valid solutions, because after all for equality to hold both sides must have the same sign.

And notice one thing, when you have the equation: $y = x^2 - 2cx + c^2$ you can't say you are solving it by saying $x = c$ is the only solution. This would be the case if you worked with $x^2 - 2cx + c^2 = \textbf{0}$, but here you have got equation of a curve so the information $x^2 - 2cx + c^2 =  0 \iff x = c$ tells you nothing more that the fact, that point $(x,y) = (c,0)$ belongs to it and the are no other points with $y$ coordinate equal to $0$ that belong to it.

Rupert Rybka Could you please show me how you do it? regarding the same-signed constrain?
p.s
If possible please do it in your answer, the formatting there is more clear.

This constraint is here the thing that you called "implicit definition constraint" so there would be nothing new in my approach (you can ommit non-positive case since $\sqrt{y}$ cannot be negative and case when both sides are $0$ is anyway included when you say they are non-negative).

Ah, so you actually approved what I said above when I asked "Right?"?
In other words, if I skipped it I will never know I made a mistake unless I go back and notice the issue. Right

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
